# Can Jasper report use both connection and bean togehter?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource

In my case i need to use both JRBeanCollectionDataSource and embedded query in jasper report.

if i need a connection i feed the report as below ,

```
JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, hm, ds.getConnection() );
```

and if i have a collection to show in report, feed as below ,

```
JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, hm, getBeanDataSource());
```

`getBeanDataSource` method returns a `JRBeanColleactionDataSource` object contains the desired data in it .

Both works fine. But in some cases i need to feed a section of a report with beans and an other with query. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, The main report needs one datasource, but you can use sub reports within your report and if you like to send the datasource you do it trough the parameters.

```
HashMap<String,Object> hm= new HashMap<String,Object>();
hm.put("datasource", getBeanDataSource());
```

in jrxml

```
<parameter name="datasource" 
 class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
```

the subreport to use this datasource would be something like this

```
<subreport>
  <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-20" y="28" width="595" height="102" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="84c78233-8870-4563-9138-e166bb6000fd"/>
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{datasource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
   <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{your sub report jrxml}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```